# How does Spark process parquet files when there are filters and recommendations for efficiency

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Let's suppose you have very big parquet files from which you want to filter a subset and save it:

```scala
val df = spark.read.parquet(inputFileS3Path)
    .select(c1, c2, c3)
    .where("c1 = '38940f'")
df.write.parquet(outputFileS3Path)
```

Does Spark read in memory all the parquet files first and then does the filtering? Is there a way in which for example, Spark reads just a batch and keep in memory only the records that satisfy the filter condition?

I am running Spark 2.2 in a Zeppelin notebook and what it seems is happening is that it reads all in memory and then does the filtering, making the process crashing sometimes (in the Spark Web UI, the input in the stage is like > 1TB but the output in S3 is 1 MB).

Is there a more efficient way to filter these files (whether is changing code, file formats, Spark version etc. etc.)?
I already select just a subset of the columns, but it doesn't seem enough.

**UPDATE**

After further investigations, I noticed that Spark was reading all in, in case the filter is on a nested field:

```scala
val df = spark.read.parquet(inputFileS3Path)
    .select(c1, c2, c3)
    .where("c1.a = '38940f'")
df.write.parquet(outputFileS3Path)
```

And I think the functionality is still not implemented (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17636).
Do you have any tips besides rewriting all the parquets with the nested fields explicit? Is there a way to force the optimizer to build a better plan?

Comment: Yes it does! When you perform a read action, all the data will be **in memory**. Spark is an in-memory processing. For better performances in terms of parallelization, it's recommended to **manage your partitions**.
Are you running you Zeppelin Notebook **locally** ?

Answer (score 1):

Spark supports predicate pushdown for top level fields.

Use `df.explain()` method to check the query plan. You should see something like:

```
   +- FileScan parquet [c1#413,c2#414,c3#415] Batched: false, 
      Format: Parquet, Location: TahoeLogFileIndex[file:/inputFileS3Path], PartitionCount: 4320, PartitionFilters: [], 
      PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(c1), EqualTo(c1,38940f)], 
      ReadSchema: struct<c1:string,c2:string,c3:string>
```

The important parts are **PushedFilters** to check the predicate pushdown and **ReadSchema** to check schema pruning.

As you've mentioned in your question predicate pushdown for nested fields is not supported. However you can optimise your query performance on nested fields with schema pruning.

Check my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331007/efficient-reading-nested-parquet-column-in-spark/57342575#57342575) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does something called predicate pushdown wherein it will filters files based on the predicates that you pass in your SQL context which in this case is `c1 = '38940f'`

In your case you would need to use the `filter` api to do predicate pushdown as shown below

```
inputDF.filter(_.birthYear == 1999)
```