# Does Spark support column scan pruning for array of structs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame named "household" in following schema:

```
root
 |-- country_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- region_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- individuals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- individual_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id_last_seen: date (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- year_released: integer (nullable = true)
```

I can use the following code to find the households that contain at least one device that was released after the year 2018

```
val sql = """
select household_id
from household
where exists(individuals, id -> exists(id.ids, dev -> dev.year_released > 2018))
"""
val v = spark.sql(sql)
```

It works well, however, I found the spark query planner was not able to prune the unneeded columns. The plan shows that Spark has to read all columns of the nested structures

Tested this with spark 2.4.5 and 3.0.0, got the same result.

Just wonder if Spark supports or will add support to column scan pruning for an array of structs?

Comment: Did your query run slowly? As far as I know, pruning only applies to partitions in Spark.

Comment: It was slow as Spark had to read all the columns in nested structs even though only one was actually used

Comment: You would probably need to normalize the ids array into a new dataframe. That would only be worth it if the select statement will be run frequently, however.

Comment: Recent spark versions do  support pruning nested columns, but still not 100%. You can try out https://github.com/taboola/ScORe, might work. You can also provide the schema manually.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

To activate the nested schema pruning, you have to set that option on the context:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.nestedSchemaPruning.enabled", "true")
```

Check this answer here:
[Efficient reading nested parquet column in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57331007/efficient-reading-nested-parquet-column-in-spark)

Comment: It is now set to true by default after Spark 3.0.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29805)